# LWC Datatable with Edit button unable to grab ID in Row Action

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

My first LWC.

This datatable will show a list of `Lean__Issuelog__c` objects with an edit button that will open the record in a new window allowing edit.  When I click the edit button I receive

> A URL cannot be created to navigate to route "standard__recordPage

It appears I am not grabbing the ID.  Any assistance to get the ID and navigate to the edit record page is appreciated.

[image: Results]

HTML

```html
 <template>     
         <lightning-datatable
             key-field="Id"
             data={issueLogData}
             show-row-number-column
             hide-checkbox-column
             onrowaction={navigateToEditAccountPage}
             columns={coulumList}>
     </lightning-datatable>        
 
</template>
```

JS

```js
 import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
 import lwcAddEditButtonToTable from '@salesforce/apex/lwcAddEditButtonToTable.getIssueLogList';
 import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
     const columns = [
         {
             type:"button",
             fixedWidth: 150,
             typeAttributes: {
                 label: 'Edit',
                 name: 'edit',
                 variant: 'brand'
             }
         },       
         {label: 'KanbanCard Name', fieldName: 'Lean__KanbanCard__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'IssueLog Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Score', fieldName: 'Lean__Score__c', type: 'Number'},
         {label: 'Weight', fieldName: 'Lean__Weight__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Probability', fieldName: 'Lean__Probability__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Detail', fieldName: 'Lean__Detail__c', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'Resolved', fieldName: 'Lean__Resolved__c', type: 'text'}
     ];
 export default class LwcAddEditButtonToTable extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
     @api recordId;
     @api issueLogData;
     @api coulumList = columns;
     @api error;
  
     @wire(lwcAddEditButtonToTable)
         wiredData({error, data }){
             if (data){
                 console.log('Data \n', data);
                 this.issueLogData = data;
                 this.error = undefined;
             }
             else if (error){
                 console.error('Error:', error);
             }
         }
 
         navigateToEditAccountPage(LightningElement){
             console.log('Record Id ==> '+ this.recordId);
             this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                 type:'standard__recordPage',
                 attributes:{
                     recordId:'this.recordId',
                     objectApiName:'Lean__IssueLog__c',
                     actionName: 'edit'
                 }
             });
         }
}
```

JS-Meta

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
     <isExposed>true</isExposed>
     <targets>
         <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
         <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
         <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
         <target>lightning__HomePage</target>       
     </targets>
 </LightningComponentBundle>
```

APEX

```java
public with sharing class lwcAddEditButtonToTable {
     
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) 
       public static List<Lean__IssueLog__c> getIssueLogList(List issueIds){
        List<Lean__IssueLog__c> issueLogList = new List<Lean__IssueLog__c>();
          
        return [
                SELECT Id,  Lean__KanbanCard__c, Name,  Lean__Score__c, Lean__Weight__c, Lean__Probability__c, Lean__Detail__c, Lean__Resolved__c
                FROM Lean__IssueLog__c
                WHERE Id IN :issueIds
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
            ];
        
        
               
           try {
               
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
           }
    
           
            return issueLogList;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is from a local development server - which doesn't provide the functionality of filling out your `recordId` like it was on a lightning page (`@api recordId`). You'll note the [unsupported features](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/lwc-localdev-supported-modules#unsupported-features) section lists `Lightning Pages`.

> Unsupported Features
>
> - Lightning Pages
> - Lightning Locker Salesforce
> - Standard Design Tokens and Custom Tokens in CSS files

This is why your console log is showing `undefined` for `this.recordId`.

You'll want to test this on a record page where the `recordId` will be filled

Even when you do that, you're currently passing in a string into `recordId` for `NavigationMixin.Navigate` instead of the variable that is supposed to have the `recordId`

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type:'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: this.recordId, //pass variable, no quotes
        objectApiName:'Lean__IssueLog__c',
        actionName: 'edit'
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `@api recordId` gets the value from the record page and since you're trying to run this component on the local development server, it won't capture the record id. And for this use case, you don't even need this property since it will be captured from the data table.
2. To capture the record id from the data table row you need to modify your code:

   ```
   navigateToEditAccountPage(event){
       this.recordId = event.detail?.row?.Id;
       console.log('Record Id ==> '+ this.recordId);
           this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
               type:'standard__recordPage',
               attributes:{
                   recordId: this.recordId,
                   objectApiName:'Lean__IssueLog__c',
                   actionName: 'edit'
           }
       });
   }
   ```